# How to combine Nested ANOVA and probabilty calculations?

Tags: probability

I have nested (hierarchical) design (zones, beaches nested within zone, sites inside beaches and then plots inside site). I want to see how invasive and native macroalgae distribution changes on each level of hierarhical design. I have 2 questions: 
1. How can I calculate the probability that in, let's say 30 plants collected randomly (as in my sampling design), 1% of them will be invasive plants?
2. How many individuals I would have to collect to have 95% probability of collecting invasive plants?
My assupmtion is that for each hierarchical level I would calculate probability independently.
Many thanks for help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not obviously related to programming.

Comment: I was thinking if somebody could maybe provided with code for R...I did not emphasize that.

Comment: You could edit your question to mention that, but you should try yourself first and show the R code of how far you got. Just asking for code without showing your own attempts is also not appreciated.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice. Once I find an example I will edit my question.

Comment: This is a great question, but it's really more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. My $0.02 in the interim: as you move forward with your study, emphasize quantifying effect sizes instead of p-values. Effect size in this context means proportions of native and invasive species. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Hi Robert, many thanks for the suggestion! I will try to ask a question in  stats.stackexchange.com. The problem is that I am not mathematician so in order ot run any code I need to write mathematical formula and I do not know where to start. I was looking for the example but couldnt find any. But I will focus on effect size, that is a good suggestion.